# How to identify subsets with continuous index within dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe which is defined like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[5,8,96,3,5,41,2,45,7,8], 'B':[1,2,3,5,6,10,11,12,13,18]})
df = df.set_index('B')
df.index.name = None
```

My goal is to assign to the dataframes subsets which have a continuous index a value like so:

[image]

**Algorithm**: As you can see from the image the first 3 rows have index 1,2,3 which increase by 1 (thus continuous). Therefore I assign to this subset them value 0 in column C.
The second subset is formed by rows having the continuous indexes 5 and 6 (note there is no index 4!). Therefore I assign to them the value 1 in column C.

**Question**: Do you know an efficient and smart way to achieve such result? I was able to achieve such result by using a a lot of for loops and ifs but it was pretty nasty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `diff` with `cumsum`; Calculate the `diff`, check whether it's equal to 1 (consecutive condition) and then `cumsum` (count) the non consecutive jumps:

```
df['C'] = df.index.to_series().diff().ne(1).cumsum().sub(1) 

df
#     A  C
#1    5  0
#2    8  0
#3   96  0
#5    3  1
#6    5  1
#10  41  2
#11   2  2
#12  45  2
#13   7  2
#18   8  3
```