# How to identify one column with continuous number and same value of another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with two columns `A` and `B`.

I want to create a new column named `C` to identify the continuous `A` with the same `B` value.

Here's an example

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,5,6,10,11,12,13,18], 'B':[1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4]})
```

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50723114/7347925), but that method only identifies the continuous `A` regardless of `B`.

```
df['C'] = df['A'].diff().ne(1).cumsum().sub(1)
```

I have tried to groupby `B` and apply the function like this:

```
df['C'] = df.groupby('B').apply(lambda x: x['A'].diff().ne(1).cumsum().sub(1))
```

However, it doesn't work: TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index.

The expected output is

```
A   B   C
1   1   0
2   1   0
3   2   1
5   2   2
6   3   3
10  3   4
11  3   4
12  3   4
13  4   5
18  4   6
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's create a sequential counter using `groupby`, `diff` and `cumsum` then `factorize` to reencode the counter

```
df['C'] = df.groupby('B')['A'].diff().ne(1).cumsum().factorize()[0]
```

Result

```
    A  B  C
0   1  1  0
1   2  1  0
2   3  2  1
3   5  2  2
4   6  3  3
5  10  3  4
6  11  3  4
7  12  3  4
8  13  4  5
9  18  4  6
```

Comment: Ha, nice answer! Could you explain how `factorize` works? If I delete it, the `C` is all 1 value. Have no idea the things behind it.

Comment: `factorize` is used to assign a sequential number to identify the distinct values in an array. For example consider the operation: `pd.Series([1, 7, 7, 9]).factorize()[0]` this will return `array([0, 1, 1, 2])`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) with compare not equal `1` and [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), last subtract `1`:

```
df['C'] = df.groupby('B')['A'].diff().ne(1).cumsum().sub(1)
print (df)
    A  B  C
0   1  1  0
1   2  1  0
2   3  2  1
3   5  2  2
4   6  3  3
5  10  3  4
6  11  3  4
7  12  3  4
8  13  4  5
9  18  4  6
```